# cross-platform setup.py using boost::python

Tags: python, cross-platform, distutils, boost-python

I would like to upload a small setup.py-based (distutils) module to pypi, so that it is easy_install'able (also under windows). The module is a single compiled extension  compiled from several files. It links agains `boost_python` and needs [Eigen3](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org) headers installed. Currently I use in `setup.py`

```
 setup(
    # usual stuff here
    ext_modules=[Extension('foo',sources=[...],
       libraries=['boost_python'],
       include_dirs=['/usr/include/eigen3'],
    )]
 )
```

This works just fine under Linux, but what about Windows? I suppose I will get in trouble quickly. I am not bound to `distutils`, a solution using `distutils2` or `setuptools` or whatever would be great.

**EDIT:** I am more asking about finding the `boost_python` library (since boost::python is used quite widely, hence somone was probably facing the same problem) rather than finding Eigen3 headers.

Comment: Does Eigen actually install its headers to `/usr/include/eigen3`? Its documentation suggests include paths of the form `<Eigen/Foo>` instead of `<eigen3/Eigen/Foo>`...

Comment: @larsmans: the packaged version installs into `/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/...` and the include is as you write: `<Eigen/Foo>`.

Comment: Strange; that means you may have to change the include path even between Linux installations. I'd consider that a bug in Eigen. (Sorry, I know that won't solve your problem.)

Comment: It is the packager's decision where to install Eigen, and they wanted to have eigen3 and eigen2 installable in parallel. The question is about windows, though.